flyback trasformer 325->12 Dc / 2-3A
I m trying to design my first circuit for switching supply power 220AC to 12Vdc. My pcb has a voltage 12dc for elettromechanic components and 3.3dc per logic with microprocessor
I Connect the 220V AC input to a rectifier to convert AC to DC.
I Use a filter capacitor to smooth the rectified voltage, resulting in approximately 325V DC.
VIPer12ADIP and Transformer
I Connect the primary winding of the transformer to the drain of the VIPer12ADIP and the rectified 325V DC input.
The VIPer12ADIP will control the switching to drive the transformer.
I could use a LM2596 for 12V to 3.3V conversion. My first doubt is what flyback transformer to use for 325V to 12V:the trasformation ratio is about 0,0369. Is possible to find a trasformer for arriving to this target without using additional  regulator ?

You can read this note ... https://www.st.com/resource/en/technical_note/tn0023-discontinuous-flyback-transformer-description-and-design-parameters-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Using Viper12A you will not reach 36 W on the output.
